# Java 11 + Chrome/Firefox = TLS decrypt error

Tags: java, ssl, java-11

I'm currently migrating some server software from Java 8 to Java 11. Everything works fine except for the fact that TLS connections are refused when my server runs on Java 11 (and only 11). I.e., everything works when running on up to and including Java 10. As soon as I switch to Java 11 (with absolutely no code changes inbetween, of course) I get a TLS decrypt error. My application works fine otherwise when I disable SSL/TLS or when I use IE/Edge to connect to my server (via TLS). When using Chrome 70 or Firefox 62 I get `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` or `SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE`, respectively.

I tried to analyze this using WireShark (see my [dump](https://nofile.io/f/dTZzcTfAzsT)). My conclusion is that Java 11 and Chrome/Firefox negotiate a bad cipher suite (rsa_pss_rsae_sha256), which somehow doesn't work with Java 11. Java 8 and IE/Edge seem to negotiate a different cipher suite (rsa_pkcs1_sha256), which works.

Does someone know how to fix this problem or at least work around it for the moment (other than disabling SSL/TLS or using IE/Edge, of course)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java 11 was released less than a month ago. Do you really want to run production on something this new?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Who said I'm running this in production? I'm currently only in the process of migration. This is a step I'll have to do eventually. And I'd rather do it sooner than later, since Java 8 will be obsolete by january.

Comment: I would test your server with CURL (uses AFAIK also NSS library like Firefox) and OpenSSL. Both tools allow to get more detailed error messages than Firefox. Also disabling TLS1.3 on Java side may be worth a try.

Comment: Have you tried an [SSL debug](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) option? If yes please paste the trace here.

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Oracle's JDK? I think that OpenJDK is missing some certificates. Maybe that's the reason

Comment: @Robert I already tried CURL and OpenSSL. Both have the same problem in that they negotiate a different cipher, which does not produce this error.

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Yeah, I've tried that already. All in all it only says I get a `SSLHandshakeException` with the message `decrypt error`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using Oracle JDK on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely to be a compatibility failure with the new PSS algorithms in TLS 1.3. You can read a good explanation for the reasoning behind the introduction of PSS [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58708).

Until it's fixed you can prevent your server from negotiating TLS 1.3 by editing `lib/security/java.security` and adding TLSv1.3 to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property.

Comment: I thought as much. I also found that neither TLS 1.3 nor 1.2 are working for me. I have to disable both in Firefox to get it working. But thanks for your workaround, I'll try it out.

Comment: I tried your solution. It doesn't work when I disable TLS 1.3 (and 1.2), because my JDK somehow falls back to TLS 1.0 and then proceeds to spit out a horrible amount of exceptions. I **did** manage to get it to work when I disabled RSA-PSS (by inserting all possible variations of `RSA(SSA)?[-_]PSS` into `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`). So, thank you!

Comment: @yetanotheruser98345873498 can you please paste here the entire jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms property you used? Thnks!

Comment: @sergiofbsilva You need to append `, RSASSA-PSS` to `jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms` in your `${JAVA_HOME}/conf/security/java.security` to disable all broken signature schemes which use this algorithm in OpenJDK 11. I also found the corresponding bug report https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216039. I also want to post the actual error message to help other people in finding this solution: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: decrypt_error". This error message can only be seen if `javax.net.debug` system property is enabled (I used `-Djavax.net.debug=all`).

Comment: Hi all, does anyone found a solution on this issue with Java 11, I tried to add RSASSA-PSS to jdk.jar.disabledAlgorithms in conf/security/java.security but still have the issue

Comment: Was hopeful but this does not fix it for me (openjdk-11.0.2, oraclejdk-11.0.2), nor did trying openjdk-12. :-(